# JWT Java client implementation RestTemplate

Tags: client, jwt, resttemplate

I have to implement client for service which is secured by JWT is there implementation of that (i prefer something like RestTemplate extention like OAuth2RestTemplate), maybe is somewere tutorial how to customize RestTemplate to implement JWT?